# Reduce width and height of fillPatternImage within kinetic circle

Tags: html5-canvas, html5-video, kineticjs

Is it possible to reduce width and height of  fillPatternImage in circle as we wish which is based on radius?

please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the fillPatternScaleX and fillPatternScaleY properties to adjust the pattern's scale factor.